# Form validation errors inside form spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, jsp-tags

I am trying to print form validation next to each field. My jsp file looks like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .error {
         color: red; font-weight: bold;
         }
      </style>
      <title>
         FORM
      </title>

   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrap" >
         <div  class= "container" style="min-height:400px;">

            <hr>
            <form:errors path="applicant.applicant_email" cssClass="error"/>
            <form:form method = "post" action = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addApplicant" modelAttribute = "applicant">

               <form:errors path="applicant.applicant_email" cssClass="error"/>
               <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input name = "applicant_email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
                  <input type = "submit" />
               </div>
            </form:form>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- div Wrap ka End -->
      <hr>
      <br>
      <br>
   </body>
</html>
```

"Applicant" is the name of my model class.

Now it prints fine outside the form, but prints nothing if form:errors is used inside form:form tag. What am I missing. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured put what the problem was. All had to do was add path attributes to the input fields. Like in my example:

```
<input name = "applicant_email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" path = "applicant_email">
```